# Scaling of SkSpriteNodes with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scaling, skspritenode

im a game i am developing i have various nodes that zoom.

depending on the device (ipad/iphone) they have a maximum size between 50-128 (output of `println("\(size)")`), so i asume the maximal size should be 3x128, right?

when zooming the following happens:

- initial size (0,0)
- final size (max,max) -- these are the sizes mentioned above

i am zooming with an SKAction like so:

```
let imageName = NameGenerator.defaultGenerator.generateAssetName(properties: properties)
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

let initialSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
let scaleFactor = max / initialSize.width
let actionScale = SKAction.scaleTo(scale, duration: duration)

node.runAction(scale)
```

so far so good. the app runs smoothly and everything works, **but**

- nodes are highly pixelated during the scaling animation

my assets are currently only stored in `@3x` size at `300x300px`

**question**

- what is the optimal texture format (png, svg,...) - is there a way to use vector images?
- what do you think is the optimal texture size for this szenario?
- am i doing the scaling / initialization right or should i do something different to avoid pixelation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be fine if you use png files. Vector formats are not supported. If you wanted to use them, you'd have to convert it to a bitmap image format like png.

As far as optimal texture size, this is really going to be a matter of trial and error as well as weighing the tradeoffs.

When scaling up, you are going to see pixelation. Just how much depends on what scale factor you are using, the actual texture itself, as well as any additional transforms you have (eg. rotation). When determining the size of the texture to use, you're basically balancing memory versus visual quality. If you do not have a lot of textures, for example, you can more than likely get away with using the larger image. Also note that scaling down has its drawbacks as well, such as aliasing effects.

What you may want to try and do is determine what you think the "optimal" or most frequently used size will be. And use that size as your x1 scale size.

Game dev is all about a balancing act of resources/performance and what the user experiences. You'll need to try and find the best tradeoff for your game.

BTW, I found this statement a little confusing:

> depending on the device (ipad/iphone) they have a maximum size between
>   50-128 (output of println("(size)")), so i asume the maximal size
>   should be 3x128, right?

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to say by this.

Comment: i am determining the max size with a screen ratio to make the game run smoothly and balanced on all ios devices. this means that the sizes vary a bit dpending on the device used.